# Query Membership using Linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I am not a experienced programmer, I need to query the Membership User Collection provided in asp.net mvc.

I want the members be able to add other members as friends, I have created a added friend table.

Id,
MemberId,
Friend_MemberId,
DateAdded

I want to display a list of Members which are not added to this list (like filter already existing friends), but unable to query using linq, can anyone suggest a way, links, articles, would it be better to extend memebership class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a number of ways you could go about this.

Let's examine one.

You can download the working VS2008 solution [**here**](http://skysanders.net/files/MembershipFriends.zip). The example is not an MVC project, but the membership provider works the same regardless.

Stipulations:

- You are using default default SqlProviders
- You know how to add an ADO.Net Entity Model using the ASPNETDB
- Your ASPNETDB serves one application, the default '/'. If this is not the case then you will already have the necessary knowledge to adjust the following guidance.

Create the Friends table in the ASPNETDB:

The following assumes that you are using the default ASPNETDB that is created in app_data. If not, then you have already created and connected to another DB, just take what you need.

- Select your project in Solution Explorer, click 'show all files' icon at the top of Solution Explorer, expand 'App_Data' folder and right-click>Open ASPNETDB.MDF.
- In Server Explorer you will see your ASPNETDB.
- Project>Add New Item>Text File>Friends.sql
- Paste query below. Save.
- Right click in editor>Connection>Connect>select ASPNETDB
- Right click in editor>Execute SQL

Friends.sql

```
/* To prevent any potential data loss issues, you should review this script in detail before running it outside the context of the database designer.*/
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET ARITHABORT ON
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
COMMIT
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.Friends
    (
    Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
    MemberId uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    Friend_MemberId uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    DateAdded datetime NOT NULL
    )  ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table1 ADD CONSTRAINT
    DF_Table1_DateAdded DEFAULT GetDate() FOR DateAdded
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table1 ADD CONSTRAINT
    PK_Table1 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
    Id
    ) WITH( STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table1 ADD CONSTRAINT
    IX_Table1 UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
    (
    MemberId,
    Friend_MemberId
    ) WITH( STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table1 SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
GO
COMMIT
```

Add an ADO.Net Entity Data Model to your project and include, at the minimum, the following:

**Tables**

- Friends

**Views**

- vw_aspnet_MembershipUsers

Query Example:

NOTE: I am by no means a Linq guru. These queries work fine and the generated sql does not seem unreasonable to me, but I am sure there is someone who will have helpful suggestions regarding possible optimizations of the queries.

```
// there are 3 users: User1, User2 and User3

// User1 has one friend, User2

string username = "User1"; // this would be the User.Identity.Name (currently logged in user)

// 

vw_aspnet_MembershipUsers[] friends;
vw_aspnet_MembershipUsers[] notFriends;

using (var ctx = new ASPNETDBEntities())
{
    // get the userId
    Guid userId = ctx.vw_aspnet_MembershipUsers.First(m => m.UserName == username).UserId;




    var usersFriendsQuery = from friend in ctx.Friends
                            join muser in ctx.vw_aspnet_MembershipUsers on friend.Friend_MemberId equals muser.UserId
                            where friend.MemberId == userId
                            select muser;


    friends = usersFriendsQuery.ToArray();

    Debug.Assert(friends.Count()==1);
    Debug.Assert(friends[0].UserName=="User2");



    var usersNotFriendsQuery = from muser in ctx.vw_aspnet_MembershipUsers
                               where ctx.vw_aspnet_MembershipUsers.Any(m =>
                                   ctx.Friends.FirstOrDefault(friend =>
                                       // include self in excluded members
                                       (muser.UserId == userId)
                                       ||
                                           // include already friends in excluded members
                                       (friend.MemberId == userId && friend.Friend_MemberId == muser.UserId)
                                       ) == null)
                               select muser;


    notFriends = usersNotFriendsQuery.ToArray();

    Debug.Assert(notFriends.Count() == 1);
    Debug.Assert(notFriends[0].UserName == "User3");
}

// do something interesting with friends and notFriends here
```